# Accidentally rejected the edit request

Tags: discussion

I was asked for an edit to my answer. but I was also editing the same answer. Somehow the proposed edit was rejected. I could not able to find the request again. I think it is quite rude to the proposer of edit. What should I do now?

Comment: If you agree with their edit then contact them and let them know what happened.

Answer (score 2):

If you have rejected it, then you've rejected it. There is no way to undo this action.

The user who suggested the edit could resubmit it but since their first attempt to edit it was rejected it is unlikely they'll do this.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can see his suggested edit and apply it yourself.